# GADTs: Difference between 'Algebraic' and 'Abstract'?

Tags: haskell, abstract-data-type, algebraic-data-types, gadt

It seems the terms "Generalised *Abstract* Data Type" and "Generalised *Algebraic* Data Type" are used interchangeably, but I am sure that technically they are not the same thing.

Could someone explain the difference, perhaps using a simple example in the context of Haskell?

Comment: AFAIK, "GADT" in Haskell always means Generalized Algebraic Data Type.  The term "Abstract Data Type" comes from the object oriented programming world and refers to something completely different.  Where did you see "Generalised Abstract Data Type"?

Comment: Mostly all the search results I see for "Generalized Abstract Data Type" appear to be people who are using the term to refer to what we would usually call a "GADT" or "Generalized Algebraic Data Type".

Comment: I guess you guys are right, in my lecture slides at uni it was written as G-Abstract-DT, might be a typo there. It definitely confused me lol.

Comment: @KeshavKini, agreed, with the one nit that abstract data types have nothing to do with OO. In fact, they are the antipode to OO-style abstraction. ML, and even Haskell to some degree, support ADTs through their module system.

Comment: Btw, some of the early papers on GADTs called them GRDTs (R = recursive), since ADT has a long-established meaning as abstract data type, and its reading as algebraic DT was probably a misunderstanding in most cases.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg Kent Pettersson and I called them Silly Type Families over 20 years ago. :)

Comment: @augustss: Lennart, I wonder why that didn't stick? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no independent concept named *generalized abstract data type*. The phrase "generalized abstract data type" is sometimes incorrectly used for *generalized algebraic data type*. This mistake arises because both "algebraic data type" and "abstract data type" are abbreviated as "ADT".

Comment: Cheers boss, understood :)